# Apply a weighted value to a dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with an outcome flag which indicates whether a row has 'Good' or 'Bad' performance. My dataset has 83,337 records, of these there are only 150 'Bads' while the remainder are 'Goods'.

I'm using this dataset to get the value of information for the variables compared to the outcome flag, I use the code below for this:

```
all_data_IV <- smbinning.sumiv(all_data,y="OUTCOME_FLAG")
```

This gives a list of all variables and their IV for the outcome flag.

My problem is, I don't have enough 'Bads' to make this reliable and would therefore need to reduce the number of 'Goods' in the dataset.

I'd like to reduce the number of 'Goods' to 10,000 rows and keep 150 'Bads', but then weight up the 'Goods' so that it's a fair representation. So that the weight would be as follows:

```
        No Records  Sample  Weight
Goods   83773       10000   8.37
Bads    150          150    1
```

In SAS if you want to apply a weight to a dataset you do something like the following:

```
/*CODING WEIGHT VALUE*/
DATA DEV_SAMPLE; SET DEV_SAMPLE;
IF FLAG = "DV" THEN WEIGHT_VALUE = 1;
ELSE WEIGHT_VALUE = 8.37;

/*APPLYING WEIGHT VALUE*/
PROC FREQ DATA = DEV_SAMPLE;
TABLE ARREARS;
WEIGHT WEIGHT_VALUE;
```

Does anyone know how to replicate this in R so I can apply a weight to the new sample?

Comment: In R weight will more likely be part of the technique you are modelling. So randomForest or gbm or xgboost's relevant function will have weight parameter through which you can pass weight parameter.

Comment: @abhiieor do you know of a way to do this when using the smbinning package? I'm trying to get an initial idea of variables that are statistically connected to the outcome flag.

Comment: I dont know much about smbbinning package but there are many such methods few documented here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#univariate-feature-selection ..Just search corresponding R function

Comment: The `svydesign()` function should be useful. Have a look at [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/3.33/topics/svydesign).